# How to add color name before product name in mini-cart and right sidebar of checkout page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, checkout, template, mini-cart

I want to show the color with the product name in Minicart and Checkout Page in Magento 2.

So i have got the color value by

```
<!-- ko if: options.length -->
                <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                    <!-- ko if: option.label == "Colour"-->
                        <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                        <!-- ko ifnot: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                            <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    <!--/ko-->
                <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
```

but the issue is when i used it with `<a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, text: product_name">` it doesn't work with it.

So any idea what I am doing wrong here and how to add color with the product name.

Comment: have you check that how you able to use the product object here?

Comment: No it didn't show anywhere on console or in data bind just show data like option and name.

Comment: first check how you get that object here and then you can use that one.

Comment: Do you have any idea how do i get that ?

Comment: I can get the product data but still the product url is in attr and color option is in html how to show then as they are not text value.

Comment: I have got the product data but how to get the color attribute value like $this->getOptionList it will give the all data but i want just Color.